# How to redirect to home page After Submitting the form in Laravel

Tags: php, validation, redirect

**This Is Form Controller How can I redirect to Home Page after submission of form?**
or redirect to any url?

```
public function sendEmail(Request $request){
            $this->validate($request, [
                            'fullname' => 'required',
                            'phonenumb' => 'required',
                            'mail' => 'required',
                   ]);
    
            Mail::send('email', [
                    'fullname' => $request->get('fullname'),
                    'phonenumb' => $request->get('phonenumb'),
                    'mail' => $request->get('mail') ],
                    function ($message) {
                            $message->from('example@domain.com');
                            $message->to('example@domain.com', 'Subject')
                                    ->subject('New candidate for Job ');
            });
    
            return back()->with('success', 'Thanks for contacting me, I will get back to you soon!');
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: `return redirect($url)`  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects

Answer (score 1):

You can use route:

```
return redirect()->route('profile');
```

Comment: should i use it in controller?

Comment: yes, you can use it in controller

Comment: Its Showing me error
""Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.google.com/' (redirected from 'https://domainname/sendemail') from origin 'https://domainname.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.""

Comment: That's from your code! You're trying to send mail and was blocked by CORS policy. You can read about CORS online

Comment: its also not redirecting on website page

Answer (score 0):

Using the `redirect`helper

redirect to route

`return redirect()->route('home');`

redirect to different url

`return redirect('https://www.google.com/');`

[more](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects) about redirects in laravel